# How to use IDREF

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm writing an XML document and trying to also state its specification.

I think that I can specify that the attribute of a tag can limited to an attribute of another tag, and I think that can be done using the `!ATTLIST`'s `IDREF`, but I'm not too sure.  Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE CUSTOM_RIBBON
[
    <!ELEMENT CUSTOM_RIBBON (VERSION, ICONS, SCRIPT+, CMD_ID+, CATEGORY)>
    <!ELEMENT ICONS (#CDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT SCRIPT (#CDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT CMD_ID (SPEC)>
    <!ELEMENT CATEGORY (PANEL)>
    <!ELEMENT PANEL (BUTTON, GROUP, SEPARATOR)+>
    <!ELEMENT GROUP (BUTTON, SEPARATOR)+>
    <!ELEMENT BUTTON EMPTY>
    <!ATTLIST BUTTON name IDREF #REQUIRED>

    <!ELEMENT SEPARATOR EMPTY>

    <!ELEMENT VERSION EMPTY>
    <!ATTLIST VERSION value CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
<CUSTOM_RIBBON>
    <SCRIPT name="button1-script">
        // some script here
        messagebox("AHHH!");
    </SCRIPT>

    <CMD_ID name="button1">
        <SPEC pressed="both" script="button1-script" text="boo!" />
    </CMD>

    <CATEGORY name="Foo">
        <PANEL name="Bar">
            <BUTTON name="button1" />
        </PANEL>
    </CATEGORY>
<CUSTOM_RIBBON>
```

I'd like to specify that:

- The `BUTTON` tag must have an attribute `name` that ***must*** have the same text in a `CMD_ID` tag's `name` attribute.
- The `CMD-ID` tag has a `script` attribute that ***must*** have the same text in a `SCRIPT` tag's `name` attribute.
- If a `CMD_ID`'s `SPEC` has a `pressed` attribute of `both`, then it ***can't*** have a sibling.
- If a `CMD_ID`'s `SPEC` has a `pressed` attribute of `true` or `false`, then it ***must*** have a sibling that is `false` or `true`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it can't be done with DTD.  I will have to go with [XSD](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp) instead.